# hiding keyboard only makes keyboard semi-transparent/faded

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm hiding a keyboard from a DialogFragment using this code...

```
etCustomerLookup.hideKeyboard()
```

Extension...

```
fun View.hideKeyboard() {
    val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}
```

This is what I'm seeing....

[image]

Update: Even after commenting out the hideKeyboard() line, it changes nothing, still get the faded keyboard.  Another note - all of the buttons "under" the faded keyboard are still accessible.

Comment: Definitely weird. Can you reproduce this behaviour on other devices and the emulator? It could have something to do with the specific android skin or keyboard app you are using perhaps?

Comment: What kind of keyboard is that? And have you tried with other devices?

Comment: What keyboard do you use? Never saw this behaviour with `DialogFragment`s. Is `DialogFragment` semitransparent? Can it take a screenshot of itself (with a keyboard) and draw over?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using a window that appears on top of the keyboard, and because your view has transparency this thing happens.

Comment: I'm not using any views that appear over the keyboard.  I'm showing a dialog that has an autosuggest edittext in it, when the user selects a suggestion the dialog is dismissed and the keyboard goes from fully visible to semi-transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Please try these two,

```
    fun hideKeyboard(activity: Activity) {
        val imm: InputMethodManager = activity.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
        var view = activity.currentFocus
        //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
        if (view == null) {
            view = View(activity)
        }
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }

    fun hideKeyboardFromWindow(activity: Activity) {
        val view = activity.findViewById<View>(R.id.content)
        if (view != null) {
            val imm = activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please specify more about your condition.